# Specificity of domain of multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Say we have the function $$h(x,y) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-y^2}}$$

Is $\text{dom} \ h = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x > y^2\}$? WolframAlpha puts the additional restriction that $x > 0$, but I assume this is already implied in $x > y^2$, since $y^2$ is bounded below by $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your domain is correct. It is likely that WolframAlpha is being redundant in its domain specification because its algorithm find the constraints $x > 0$ and $x > y^2$ separately, and reports both without realizing that $x > y^2$ implies the former.

Comment: Thank you, kind sir.